# How to integrate a series of options in a string to a certain command in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, args

When I want to type `prog -a -b --hello=12 -c -d --good -e FILE1.txt FILE2.txt`, I have a string `s1="-a -b --hello=12"` and `s2="-c -d --good"`.

What can I write to use `s1` and `s2` with `prog` and two filenames to substitute that long stuff to reach the same final result in shell?

It can also be thought as what $@ do. I want `s1` and `s2` to behave as `$@` instead of being recognize as two filenames.

**My expectation can be understood as starred expression in Python.**

Is there any special operator or command in shell which can sparse a string into separated arguments?

Or if it is too difficult to resolve, answer another post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503303/what-is-the-data-structure-of-in-shell) can also be helpful.

Comment: If `s1` and `s2` contains what you've defined then you can pass `prog "$s1" "$s2" -e FILE1.txt FILE2.txt`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Inian, This is just an example, as all of options are optional, If I directly providing these two string, prog will regard them as two filenames. I want make these two thing like starred expression in Python.

Comment: @Inian, If I write what you said, then prog will regard s1 as an option 'a' with the value of ' -b --hello=12'.

Comment: Why can't you use `getopts()` inside your `prog` and parse the flags?

Comment: @Inian, Because, prog is a third-part program which is written by other people. I am just call it from my script.